# How to get coords inside a transformed sprite?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I am trying to the get the x and y coordinates inside a transformed sprite. I have a simple 200x200 sprite which rotates in the middle of the screen - with an origin of (0,0) to keep things simple.

[image: Screenshot]

I have written a piece of code that can transform the mouse coordinates but only with a specified x OR y value.

```
int ox = (int)(MousePos.X - Position.X);
int oy = (int)(MousePos.Y - Position.Y);

Relative.X = (float)((ox - (Math.Sin(Rotation) * Y /* problem here */)) / Math.Cos(Rotation));
Relative.Y = (float)((oy + (Math.Sin(Rotation) * X /* problem here */)) / Math.Cos(Rotation));
```

How can I achieve this? Or how can I fix my equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general way is to express the transformation as a matrix. This way, you can add any other transformation later, if you find you need it.

For the given transformation, the matrix is:

```
var mat = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
```

This matrix can be interpreted as the system transformation from sprite space to world space. You want the inverse transformation - the system transformation from world space to sprite space.

```
var inv = Matrix.Invert(mat);
```

You can transform the mouse coordinates with this matrix:

```
var mouseInSpriteSpace = Vector2.Transform(MousePos, inv);
```

And you get the mouse position in the sprite's local system.

You can check if you have the correct matrix `mat` by using the overload of `Spritebatch.Begin()` that takes a matrix. If you pass the matrix, draw the sprite at (0, 0) with no rotation.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked perfectly! What about if there is an origin?

Comment: Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Origin) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Rotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position)